# python: from x import y changes previous import result

Tags: python, python-import

I am trying to understand the package and module name shadowing rules in python and stumbled across a case where I do not understand why the results that I see make any sense. This cases happens for python 2 (with `from future import absolute_imports`) and python 3.

Assuming I have the following folder structure:

```
├── mypackage
│   ├── argparse.py
│   └── __init__.py
└── script.py
```

`mypackage` is my custom top-level package, where I have a module shadowing the standard `argparse` module. Inside my script I execute the following code:

```
import argparse
print(argparse)
from mypackage.argparse import foo
print(argparse)
```

The results are the ones I expect:

```
<module 'argparse' from '/usr/lib/python3.5/argparse.py'>
<module 'argparse' from '/usr/lib/python3.5/argparse.py'>
```

However, if I change my script to execute a function from my package and execute the same import and print statements in the `__init__.py` of my package, i.e.:

script:

```
from mypackage import main
main()
```

`__init__.py`:

```
import argparse
print(argparse)
from mypackage.argparse import foo
print(argparse)

def main():
    pass
```

As a result I see:

```
<module 'argparse' from '/usr/lib/python3.5/argparse.py'>
<module 'mypackage.argparse' from '/tmp/test/src/mypackage/argparse.py'>
```

Why does in this case (and not in the other one) the `from X import Y` statement override the previous global import of `argparse` to the local module?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider how you access submodules, you would write `mypackage.argparse` to access the submodule of `mypackage`.

Now consider how attribute lookup for modules work, it searches for the attribute in the modules global namespace.

Putting these two together, the only way to access submodules is by adding them to the packages global namespace, this is the intended behaviour.

Comment: Is this somehow documented somewhere? I have the feeling this make 50% of the benefits gained with absolute import useless.

Comment: The [documentation on packages](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html#packages) is seriously lacking in explaining how the `__init__.py` woks in many regards. :/

Comment: Ok, thanks. So I have no chance to deal with this apart from arranging my imports in an unusual way just to ensure that argparse is imported after the from X.... statement?

Comment: either way if you `import argparse` from the top level of your package then using `mypackage.argparse` is extremely ambiguous, I'd recommend importing `as` a different name (maybe `as _std_argparse`)

Comment: I just didn't want to use my module name at all and only the contained members. But it still seems that name clashes are a nightmare in python. I will just try to avoid it.

Comment: @languitar if you don't care what it is named why call it `argparse`? Why not just `members_container` or something similar?  I find that as long as you don't shadow builtin (and I guess other module) names and don't use `from __ import *` then there are not very many name clashes, anyway I hope you find a solution to your problem that appeals to you!

Comment: I have had several clashes fro composing several libraries and sometimes something like `mypackage.utils.argparse` is very clear by the name.