# How exactly does Python resolve "from X import Y" if there are multiple Ys in X?

Tags: python

I have a package X which contains two different things named Y

One is a module:

```
# X/Y.py
print 'hello'
```

The other is a variable:

```
# X/__init__.py
Y = 'world'
```

If I execute `from X import Y` which Y do I get and *why*? What determines the order and shadowing rules for import statements?

Lastly, is there anything I might do accidentally that would change the answer?

Basically I got a bug report that indicates on a user's machine this code results in the opposite Y importing from what I get on my machine. I don't have access to the user's machine, so I am trying to figure out what happened.

I am wondering if there are clues in this previous question:
[python: from x import y changes previous import result](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37317153/python-from-x-import-y-changes-previous-import-result)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Modules in packages, once imported, are also set as an attribute on the parent module object. The `from module import name` syntax, however, will *first* look at the attributes of the imported module object (the globals of `X`) to resolve `name`.

So, the answer is that it depends. If you have not imported the `X.Y` module yet, then you'll end up with `Y` bound to `'world'`. If you have imported `X.Y` (with `import X.Y` or `from X.Y import some_name`), then `Y` is bound to the `X.Y` submodule. The latter is a side-effect of `Y` in `X` having been set as a global.

Demo:

```
$ mkdir foo
$ cat << EOF > foo/__init__.py
> bar = 'from the foo package'
> EOF
$ cat << EOF > foo/bar.py
> baz = 'from the foo.bar module'
> EOF
$ bin/python -c 'from foo import bar; print(bar)'
from the foo package
$ bin/python -c 'import foo.bar; from foo import bar; print(bar); print(bar.baz)'
<module 'foo.bar' from 'foo/bar.py'>
from the foo.bar module
```

Answer (score 1):

A name in the module will take precedence.  From [the Python tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html#packages).

> Note that when using from package import item, the item can be either a submodule (or subpackage) of the package, or some other name defined in the package, like a function, class or variable. The import statement first tests whether the item is defined in the package; if not, it assumes it is a module and attempts to load it.

The same information is given in [the language reference](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-import-statement).

However, if any code imports the submodule (by other, more explicit means, such as `import X.Y`, where `Y` can only refer to a module), then the submodule will also exist as a name in the package.  So in that case it will depend on the order of the code: once you import the module, it will overwrite the variable of the same name.

Answer (score -1):

Python looks first on the current working directory for any file Y.py under X folder, then it looks for the installed libraries for X package to import Y file. 
If there is a Y variable in the package X then it is imported and then replaced by the content on file Y.py of that package